# Parallel for loops in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

this is my first time using VBA. My goal is to create a column of values that are the result of evaluating a function. Here is a simplified version of how I'm structuring my code.

```
Sub find_alpha()
    Dim StartNumber As Integer
    Dim EndNumber As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim alpha As Integer
    EndNumber = 39
    For alpha = 0 To 10
        For StartNumber = 1 To EndNumber
            For i = 0 To 38
                Cells(StartNumber, "A").Value = Cells.Item(1, "B") * i * (1 - alpha)
            Next i
        Next StartNumber
    Next alpha
End Sub
```

This doesn't work because it loops from 0 to 38 in only one cell, while I need it to actually move through and add the value to each cell. So the value at i=0, should go to A1, i=2 should go to A2, i=3 should go to A3, etc.

Is there a way to move through the loop in parallel to accomplish this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you post examples of the expected input and output? I can't tell from the code what you expect to see. Currently you only write the value of the last result of the inner loop.

Comment: presumably you need `StartNumber` in the right-hand-side of the assignment, maybe where the 1 is? *= Cells.Item(**1**, "B") * i * (1 - alpha)*

Comment: It's suspicious that there is a loop from 0 to 38 inside a loop from 1 to 39.  Is that intentional, or should `i` simply be `StartNumber - 1`?

Comment: If you swap your 'StartNumber' loop with your 'i' loop, you should get the desired result. But like Comintern, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question/aim isn't very clear so here are some possible blind shots:

1. place from cell "A1" down to a predefined rows number (`EndNumber`) the result of multiplying cell "B1" value by a number from 0 to `(currentRowIndex- 1) * (1 - alpha)`, where `currentRowIndex` is the row index of the current cell in column "A" being written and `alpha` varies from 0 to 10 (...)

   then you'd go:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub find_alpha1()
       Dim StartNumber As Long
       Dim EndNumber As Long
       Dim i As Long
       Dim alpha As Long

       StartNumber = 1
       EndNumber = 39
       For alpha = 0 To 10
           For i = StartNumber To EndNumber
               Cells(i, "A").value = Cells.item(1, "B") * (i - 1) * (1 - alpha)
           Next i
       Next alpha
   End Sub
   ```

   the same code could be rewritten as follows:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub find_alpha2()
       Dim EndNumber As Long
       Dim alpha As Long

       EndNumber = 39
       For alpha = 0 To 10
           With Range("A1").Resize(EndNumber)
               .FormulaR1C1 = "=R1C2*(ROW()-1)*(1-" & alpha & ")"
               .Value=.Value '<--| get rid of the formula and leave values only
           End With
       Next alpha
   End Sub
   ```

   but there would be the issue that those column "A" cells would be rewritten at every `For alpha = 0 To 10` loop ... (see below)
2. place in columns starting from "A" rightwards from row 1 to a predefined rows number (`EndNumber`) the results of multiplying cell "B1" value by a number from 0 to `(currentRowIndex- 1) * (1 - alpha)`, where `currentRowIndex` is the row index of the current cell in current column being written and with columns shifting rightwards at every `alpha` loop from 0 to 10

   for such a task you actually need to write cells from row 2 downwards in order not to overwrite cell "B1"

   then you'd go:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub find_alpha3()
       Dim EndNumber As Long
       Dim alpha As Long

       EndNumber = 39
       For alpha = 0 To 10
           With Range("A2").Offset(, alpha).Resize(EndNumber)
              .FormulaR1C1 = "=R1C2*(ROW()-2)*(1-" & alpha & ")"
              .value = .value '<--| get rid of the formula and leave values only
           End With
       Next alpha
   End Sub
   ```
3. If not 1 or 2 then what?

Comment: Thank you, the first suggestion you made is what I was looking for. If I wanted to fix the row and add numbers across columns, should I make the column letters a variable?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but you can use numeric indexs for columns. too like `Cells(1, i).value = Cells.item(2, i) * (i - 1) * (1 - alpha)` where rows 1 and 2 are _fixed_  and you iterate through columns with `i`. But in this case take care not to overwrite what's actually in "B2"